# Why does ActiveMQ Message server requires JDK, Not JRE?

Tags: activemq-classic

The ActiveMQ message broker requires Java JDK (not the Java runtime JRE). Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure that you actually do. Although it's listed on the requirements page, on http://activemq.apache.org/support.html you find

> What platform of Java (e.g., Java SE 6 with JRE/JDK 1.6.0 or J2SE 5
>   with JRE/JDK 1.5.0)

Under 'how to get help'. Have you tried it with a JRE instead of a JDK?

Comment: I tried it with JRE. No issues. But the website says I need JDK.  http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-PreInstallationRequirements

Comment: I read that too. It may simply be that JDK and JRE are occasionally used synonymously.

Comment: (More likely, the article on which the information was based, now missing at the reported link, was written by a developer who just happened to set up that way though unnecessarily.)

Answer (score 0):

From ActiveMQ [Document](http://activemq.apache.org/getting-started.html#GettingStarted-Pre-InstallationRequirements):

> Environment:
>   Java Runtime Environment (JRE)  JRE 1.7 (1.6 for version <=5.10.0)
>   (a JDK is required if you plan to recompile source code)

JRE is fine unless you have to recompile ActiveMQ.